# How to detect if mouse is clicked other than $(this) element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to apply some styling if mouse is clicked inside an element (here `.block`). If the element is clicked get that element by `$(this)` and style it. Now after that, when the user clicks other than the `$(this)` element, I would like to change it back to default styling. How do I detect if mouse is clicked other than `$(this)` element.

js script so far :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    // when a block is clicked get that specific block
    $('.block').click(function() {
        var block = $(this);
        block.css('background','red');
    });

    //if clicked other than the block do stuff

});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Aamu/ftq8a6ex/3/)

Comment: You must achieve it by simple css. See my answer

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal Yes I saw your answer and its really very interesting. But I need it to do some other jquery function too. +1 by me. Its really very good.

Comment: ok, so if you have other callbacks too, that you can achieve by listening to `focus` event on that block.

Comment: do you want stop if the click is on any of the child elements?

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan I am sorry I didn't get you. What do you mean by stop?

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal Ok, could you update your answer.

Comment: @Aamu Can you tell what other things you want to do by jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can bind the click event on the `body` and check if `#a` was clicked using `e.target` function

```js
$('div').click(function () {
    $(this).css('background', 'red')
})
$('body').click(function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).is($("#a"))) {
        
    } else {
        $('#a').css('background','tomato')
    }
})
```

```css
div {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:tomato;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a"></div>
```

Comment: Hello and thank you. But I need to change if the block obj is not clicked, because there are many `.block`s. Could you change it please. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r3tyva47/)

Answer (score 14):

The better way to do this is using `tabindex` andd css `:focus` selector

```css
.container{
  border:1px solid #333;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}
.block{
  background-color: #ccc;
  width:50px;
  float:left;
  height:50px;
  margin:20px;
}
.block:focus{
 background-color: red;
 outline:none
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block" id="block1" tabindex="1">
    </div>
  <div class="block" id="block2" tabindex="1">
    </div>
  <div class="block" id="block3" tabindex="1">
    </div>
  <div class="block" id="block4" tabindex="1">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: JS control is still possible: bind a click listener on the `document`, put the `tabindex` attributes on the relevant elements and then on click check `document.activeElement` and do something with it.

Answer (score 5):

You can try something like this:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // when a block is clicked get that specific block
    $('.block').click(function () {
        var block = $(this);
        block.css('background', 'red');
    });

    //if clicked other than the block do stuff
    $('html:not(.block)').click(function () {
        //your logic here
    });
});
```

[**`FIDDLE DEMO`**](http://jsfiddle.net/us7utdhw/)

Comment: Hi thanks. But I think you misunderstood my question a little. The block I want is the actual block obj and not the block class. Could you please change it accordingly.

Comment: @Aamu I am not getting you. Could you lease post a functional example that illustrates your problem on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 2):

Add a CSS class that represents the styles and selected state of the currently chosen block:

```
.block.selected {
  background: red;
}
```

Within the click handler, remove that class from the block that's selected.  (If no blocks are selected, `removeClass()` won't do anything.)  Then add the class to the newly-clicked block:

```
$('.block').click(function() {
  $('.block.selected').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

[**Fiddle 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/nwydf95a/)

---

**Update**

> How do I know whether it is clicked inside the block or other .block

Use [hasClass()](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) to determine if you've clicked the same block twice:

```
$('.block').click(function() {
  if($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
    // do something here
  }

  $('.block.selected').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

[**Fiddle 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/4fmes0ea/)

Comment: How do I know whether it is clicked inside the block or other .block or any other element?

Answer (score 1):

doing it in JS would be something like

```js
var globalRef;
var inside = document.querySelectorAll('.inside');

document.querySelector('.block').addEventListener('click', function (e) {

    if (globalRef != undefined) {
        globalRef.style.background = 'none'
    }

    globalRef = e.target;
    e.target.style.background = 'red'
}, false);
```

```css
.block {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:#ccc;
}
.inside {
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid green;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    float:left
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
    <div class='inside'></div>
    <div class='inside'></div>
    <div class='inside'></div>
    <div class='inside'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please update your answer according to my jsfiddle.

Comment: @Aamu here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maio/ftq8a6ex/6/) implemented in your scenario

Answer (score 1):

See the comments in the working example code below.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <style>
            .block {
                background: gray;
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;
                float: left;
                margin-left: 20px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="block" id="block1"></div>
        <div class="block" id="block2"></div>
        <div class="block" id="block3"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                /*
                Solution 1:
                This gathers all elements with the class 'block' and defines a click event on it.
                In the click event all elements with class 'block' are walked through. If an element
                has the same id as the current element's id, than do one thing else do another thing.
                In this example background color en content of the three divs are changed
                */
                $('.block').click(function(i) {
                    /*
                    Notice the usage of $(this) and this in the code below. $(this) Is the
                    jquery element while 'this' is the DOM element.
                    */
                    var block = $(this);
                    $(".block").each(function(){
                        if (this.id == block.attr("id")) {
                            this.innerHTML = ("My id is " + this.id);
                            this.style.background = "red";
                        } else {
                            this.innerHTML = "";
                            this.style.background = "gray";
                        }
                    })
                });
                /*
                Solution 2:
                For each element you want actions on, define a separate click event.
                */
                $('#block1').click(function(i) {
                  alert("You clicked me?");
                });
                $('#block2').click(function(i) {
                  alert("Why did you click me?");
                });
                $('#block3').click(function(i) {
                  alert("Hi there, what's new?");
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on Akshay's answer:

```
$('body').click(function (e) {
    var clicked = $(e.target);

    //See if the clicked element is (or is inside) a .block:
    var clickedBlock = clicked.closest('.block');
    if (clickedBlock.length) {
        clickedBlock.css('background', 'red');
    }

    //Remove the overridden background from other blocks:
    var allBlocks = $('.block');
    allBlocks.not(clickedBlock).css('background', '');
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ftq8a6ex/5/

Comment: I tried using your script, but its not working. Could you try in my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Aamu/ftq8a6ex/3/).

Comment: Updated fiddle which uses jQuery's `.closest()` to find the container `.block` of any clicked element: http://jsfiddle.net/ftq8a6ex/5/